# Template Argument Deduction from String Literal

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, string-literals, perfect-forwarding

I am currently thinking about how to best constrain a generic type of a template to an `std::sting` as well as string literals. Therefore I compare the deduced type with the desired type using `std::is_same`. In case of an `std::string` this works right away. For a string literal, meaning a char const array, it only works if I use `std::decay` on the type and then compare the result to the type `char const *`. If I directly compare the deduced type to what I think it should be, `is_same` returns false, as is illustrated by the following example code.

```cpp
template <class TYPE>
void function(TYPE&& parameter)
{
  //this doesn't work as expected
  std::cout << typeid(TYPE).name() << " : " << typeid(char const [5]).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<char const [5], TYPE>::value << std::endl;
  //this works as expected
  std::cout << typeid(std::decay_t<TYPE>).name() << " : " << typeid(char const *).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<char const *, std::decay_t<TYPE>>::value << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  function("name");
  return 0;
}
```

The output generated is the following:

```cpp
char const [5] : char const [5]
0
char const * __ptr64 : char const * __ptr64
1
```

**Now, what I am wondering is why `is_same` returns false in the first case even though the types appear to be identical.**

The only possible explanation that I could come up with is that within the function `std::is_same` a transformation similar to `std::decay` is applied to the type (for instance a function call). But then again this transformation would also occur to the other type, yielding the same result and thus resulting in equality.

Comment: Wait until C++17, and write your template to use `std::string_view`.

Comment: Try removing references from `TYPE`. String literals are lvalues.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I didn't know that. Changing the line to `std::is_same<char const [5], std::remove_reference_t<TYPE>>::value` results in equality. Why are string literals considered lvalues? If it was an int literal instead it would be considered an rvalue, wouldn't it? And can we maybe make this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals are not passed by value as `char const [N]`, but by *reference* as `char const (&)[N]`.

This works correctly for me:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<char const (&)[5], TYPE>::value << std::endl;
```

Note [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) that

> 1) Refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type type. **If type is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type**.

You can easily verify that `is_same` doesn't discard reference-ness in the same way as `type_info`, for example by checking that

```
std::is_same<int&, int>::value == false
```

This explains why the `typeid` name is the same, but your `is_same` test still fails.

Answer (score 2):

Using gcc custom function:

```
template < class T >
constexpr std::string type_name()
{
    std::string p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    return p.substr( 43 + 10, p.length() - 100 - 1 - 10 );
}
```

And adding it to your code:

```
std::cout << type_name<TYPE>() << " : " << type_name<char const [5]>() << std::endl;
```

The results are:

```
A5_c : A5_c
0
const char (&)[5] : const char [5]
```

So you need to use `std::remove_reference` on `TYPE`.

Comment: I think you are right concerning the effects. However, the cause for this was mentioned by Kerrek SB in the comments: string literals apparently are lvalues, not rvalues. Therefore the type is deduced as `T&` instead of `T` when passed via a forwarding reference parameter.

Comment: @user1488118 When you use same string literal in your code, for example `"string"` in different places, it is actually the same string. It's not new temporary each time, but it stays in the memory as long as program is running, so when you refer to it, you actually refer to it by l-value reference.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an mistake of the compiler. The compiler generates such types-objects given by typeid at compiletime. The compiler wouldn't compile array-types for each length (0 to 2**n), so it compiles them when needed, and it may "forget" about the duplicate. Try to use a special template where you seperate the length from the contained type. This is not the type but you can check if it is equal to another.

```
    template<class T, size_t size> 
struct array_t{};

    template <class T, size_t size>
void function(T[size] parameter) {
    std::cout << typeid(array_t<T, size>).name() << " : " << typeid(array_t<char, 5>).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<array_t<T, size>, array_t<char, 5>>::value << std::endl;
};
```